# Case-insensitive substring search

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find the position of a substring in another string with `IgnoreCase`.
example:

```
String str ="aabbssddaa", str2="ab";
str.indexOf(str2);
```

I want to find the position of str2 that is not case sensitive. means str2= any of them "ab","Ab","aB","AB"
And I want to traverse the string only once.

Comment: str.toLowerCase().indexOf(str2.toLowerCase()). You could do this, other way as well. I mean with uppercase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` on both strings.

Comment: thanx good logic.. :)

Comment: Except that does not always work.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @KevinPanko Any explanation of why? I'm not bit-twiddling ASCII, I'm using Java's `String` manipulations, which are explicitly defined in terms of Unicode characters. In particular, how would `toUpperCase()` and `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` differ from each other?

Comment: Check out the Turkish rules for the letter I.  Uppercase `i` and the result is `İ` which means if you do `foo.toUpperCase().equals("EXIT")` it will be true in US English and false in Turkey when `foo` is the string `"exit"`.

Comment: @KevinPanko The bug is using the wrong charset. And you still haven't said how that would differ from `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, which is the next-best option.